# How to evaluate Ansible module return values?

Tags: ansible, yaml

this is what is returned by running my playbook:

```
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "result_pub_ips_ephemeral": {
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "public_ips": []
        }
    }
```

Public_ips is empty so I assume I would be able to test this with:

```
    result_pub_ips_ephemeral.public_ips !=""
```

But it does not work. I want to use it to skip tasks when the variable is empty. How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: `Public_ips is empty` <= more precisely, it is an empty list, hence it is **not** an empty string. My preferred test here would be `when: result_pub_ips_ephemeral.public_ips | length != 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can test it with this conditional:

```
when: result_pub_ips_ephemeral.public_ips
```

If result_pub_ips_ephemeral.public_ips is empty then the task will be skipped.